# exact solution for first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I was trying to solve this non-linear first ODE

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {a*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 - b*Derivative[1][y][x]*Sqrt[3*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 - f*y[x]^2 + 3] - a*f*y[x]^2 + (a - 2/3) == 0, y[1] == y0}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {y}, {x, 0, 10}, {a, b, f, y0}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]; 
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[y[a, b, f, y0][x] /. sol], {x, 0, 10},PlotStyle -> Red], {{a, 1}, 0, 2, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},{{b, 0.3}, .1, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f, 1}, 1, 100, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{y0, 1}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I don't know why what is wrong here. Also I don't think so it has an analytical solution.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. It works on my machine. What problems do you have specifically?

Comment: `I don't think so it has an analytical solution`  V13 DSolve gives answer in terms of integrals. If you have specific values for `f` and `a` may be it can evaluate these integrals.

Comment: Try with a new kernel.

Comment: Can you show me to write an analytical solution for this?

Comment: I just did `DSolve[eqns, y[x], x]`  but the integrals are not resolved.

Comment: Can we find out for which parameter of f has analytical solution? imagine we know 1<a<2 and b=0.3

Comment: The integrals are hard to solve analytically. But it does give solutions in terms of them. So this become an integration problem really. You can try plugging in some values for `a,b,f` and see if you can get explicit solution. May be for some values these integrals can be solved. I do not know. use Manipulate to try different values?

Comment: `DSolve[]` produces something akin to a hyperelliptic integral, which do not have closed forms known to *Mathematica* in general. That those also need to be inverted afterwards (note the use of `InverseFunction[]`) does not help matters.

Answer (score 5):

The [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) controls provide machine precision parameters, the precision should be increased consistent with the precision used in the [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) before their use.

Also, depending on the parameter values, a different plot type may be more appropriate.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {a*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 - 
     b*Derivative[1][y][x]*Sqrt[3*Derivative[1][y][x]^2 - f*y[x]^2 + 3] - 
     a*f*y[x]^2 + (a - 2/3) == 0, y[1] == y0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, y, {x, 0, 10}, {a, b, f, y0}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20];

Manipulate[
 plt[
  Evaluate[(y @@ SetPrecision[{a, b, f, y0}, 20])[x] /. sol],
  {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20],
 {{a, 1}, 0, 2, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0.3}, .1, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, 1}, 1, 100, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y0, 1}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter,
 {{plt, Plot, "Plot Type"},
  {Plot, LogLinearPlot, LogLogPlot}}]
```

[image]